# how to run command “mysqladmin flush-logs” on windows

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am using a windows server for my web application. Actually the log file is too heavy and I want to reset that file. I have launched the console to flush the logs as written on mysql doc. When I type this `mysqladmin flush-logs`
I receive an error :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
admin flush_logs' at line 1
```

How do I flush logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to authenticate:

```
mysqladmin flush-logs -u[user_name] -p[password]
```